# How to link godaddy domain with application running on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running into this problem trying to link my Godaddy domain with a AWS Elastic ip.I google it and got many documents on how to link a EC2 instance with a domain on Godaddy.I followed following steps :

1: I created a new Elastic ip, and mapped to my instance aws.

2: Edit godaddy A(Host) to point to this elastic ip.

[image]

But when i am pointing to my domain name i.e http://example.com it is showing my Jboss server console.I find and got that the war file name should be ROOT.war but i am running multiple application on same server so how can i point this domain to my specific application like "http://MyExample/index.jsp"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use any reverse proxy server like Nginx and create a configuration there to map the domain to the application running on the server.

Assuming your application is running on `127.0.0.1` at port `8081` on the server then nginx config would have something like

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;`

Comment: I think u din't got what i m asking for my jboss server running multiple application each have separate domain name like abc.war with domain name abc.com, xyz.war with xyz.com

Comment: I m trying setup nginx reverse proxy with the help of this link "http://www.catchexceptions.com/server/nginx/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-server-for-jboss/" but can you please tell me where i could mentioned application name in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an application load balancer! Avoid NGINX for reverse proxying like a curse especially if you're going to down stream to an elastic load balancer that is fronting an elastic beanstalk.

Because you really should be removing your EC2 instance and running elastic beanstalks for your apps anyway :P

Comment: I don't  want to switch my traffic for same domain name, I have separate domain for each application so I don't know why should I use load balancer?

Comment: the application load balancer is also a "reverse proxy".